# What is the ::content/::slotted pseudo-element and how does it work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, web-component, shadow-dom

This is impossible to Google for because every article talking about the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements seems to use the word 'content'.

I heard about it in [this](http://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/) CSS-Tricks article, explaining how to implement an image slider as an example use-case for web components. The code example it appears inside is thus:

**CSS**

```
#slides ::content img {
   width: 25%;
   float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
  ...
  <div class="inner">
    <content select="img"></content>
  </div>
</template>
```

It seems to be referring to this `<content>` tag, which is used to allow the user to include Web Components, but I would love to understand this more deeply.

**EDIT:**

After reading further, in the aforementioned article, I discovered a link the author's "Shadow DOM CSS Cheatsheet" which includes a passage that explains what the `::content` pseudo-element is:

> Selects distributed nodes inside of an element. Needs to be paired
>   with polyfill-next-selector for browsers that do not support the
>   native selector.

```
::content h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Source: http://robdodson.me/blog/2014/04/10/shadow-dom-css-cheat-sheet/

This is helpful, but I still find the whole affair rather opaque. Any additional insights?

Comment: The [**Spec**](http://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#selectordef-content) might offer additional insight.

Comment: @Paulie_D just saw the cheatsheet (added a link in question above) - thanks! but still finding the whole concept to be unclear. what are distributed nodes?

Comment: More reading - [**HERE**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/)

Comment: **`::content` has been renamed to `::slotted`**

Comment: Thanks Oriol. @jon I've updated my answer to reflect this. Once browsers shift support to `slot` and `slotted`, I'll replace the mentions of `content` and `::content` and probably update the question as well so that it remains useful for future readers!

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The `::content` pseudo-element is being replaced in future implementations of Web Components / Shadow DOM with the `::slotted` pseudo-element. Likewise, the element targeted by this pseudo-element has changed from `<content` to `<slot`> in the latest version of the [Shadow DOM specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/). You can see related discussion about that change [here](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Apr/0239.html).

Currently browsers still support `<content>` and `::content`.

---

### Original answer:

---

**Summary:**

`::content` is essentially a way to dig deeper and style descendants of the `ShadowHost`, which normally aren't available to be styled, because your CSS doesn't know to look for the ShadowDOM fragment without `::content`.

---

This answer assumes you are at least somewhat familiar with the **[`<template>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-templates/)** element and **[Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/)**, specifically the **[ShadowDOM](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/)**, which deals with `ShadowTree`s and their two main elements, `ShadowHost` and `ShadowRoot`.

**Note** - As of this writing, there is less than 50% support (even prefixed, off-by-default support) for Web Components across the five major browsers. While all modern browsers support `<template>`, only recent versions of Chrome and Opera support the ShadowDOM fully; with Firefox supporting parts of it after you toggle the requisite feature in `about:config` (`dom.webcomponents.enabled`) to **true**.

The goal of using the `ShadowDOM` is similar to MVC's **[separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)**. That is, we want to separate our content from our presentation and allow for encapsulated templates in our code to help make it more manageable. We have this already in various programming languages, but it's remained a problem for some time in HTML and CSS. Further, there can be conflicts with class names when styling elements in web apps.

Normally, we interact with the `LightDOM` (a sort of "Light Realm"), but sometimes it would be helpful to take advantage of encapsulation. Crossing into this sort of "Shadow Realm" (part of Web Components) is a new method to prevent the problems mentioned above by **allowing encapsulation**. Any styles applied to markup in your `ShadowTree` won't apply to markup outside of your `ShadowTree`, even if the exact same classes or selectors are used.

When the `ShadowTree` (which lives in the `ShadowDOM`) has a tree from the `LightDOM` distributed within it, and/or when the `ShadowTree` is rendered, the result is converted by the browser into what is called a **[composed tree](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#composed-trees)**.

When the browser renders your code, content is being distributed and inserted at new locations *other than* where it was physically typed. This distributed output is what you see (and what the browser sees), and is called the `composed tree`. In reality, the content is not originally typed in the order that it now appears, but you won't know this, and neither will the browser. This separation between "end result" and "original code", if you will, is one of the main benefits of encapsulation.

**[Web Components & the Future of CSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHxrr6Q82yI)** is a great 40-minute video on Web Components and specifically the ShadowDOM, pointed out to me by [ZachSaucier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065702/zach-saucier).

---

Specific to your question, the `::content` pseudo element applies to what are called **distributed nodes**. A distributed node is another term for whatever you put within the `<content></content>` tags. The content is *distributed* from its place in the original markup to wherever you have placed your `<content>` tags in the template.

So, when you need specificity in CSS, one way you can handle selectors normally is that you go to the parent element and add that in as part of the selector. Ex: if `.container {}` is not specific enough, you might use `div .container {}` or `.main .container {}` in order to make your selector work.

Thinking about the point of the ShadowDOM, which is scoping and encapsulation, you have to realize that this new ShadowTree you've created is a completely new (discrete) DOM fragment. It's not in the same "Light Realm" as the rest of your content; it's in a "Shadow Realm". So, how does the CSS know to target this "Shadow Realm"? By using the `::content` pseudo-element!

### **[The `::content` pseudo-element selector acts as the parent element of distributed nodes.](http://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#content-combinator)**

HTML5Rocks has a great sequence of tutorials [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/), [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/), and [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/) which cover more information and give some great examples (be sure to visit with Chrome or Opera until more browsers support these features).

For example, see this modified and improved (by [Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032492/leo)) version of the code from HTML5Rocks:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var root = div.createShadowRoot();
var template = document.querySelector('template');

root.appendChild(template.content);
```

```html
<template>
  <style>
    h3 { color: red; }
    content[select="h3"]::content > h3 { color: green; }
    ::content section p { text-decoration: underline; }
  </style>
  <h3>Shadow DOM</h3>
  <content select="h3"></content>
  <content select="section"></content>
</template>

<div>
  <h3>Light DOM</h3>
  <section>
    <div>I'm not underlined</div>
    <p>I'm underlined in Shadow DOM!</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Also available on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/6n946pea/1/)** (Remember to visit in a WebKit-based browser like Chrome or Opera)

Here you can see that the **`::content`**`section p` pseudo element is *first* selecting the content of the `ShadowRoot`, which is the contents of the `div` element in your markup, and *then* specifying further by adding `section p`.

This may seem unnecessary when compared to normal CSS selector usage (for example, why not just use `section p {}`?), until you recall that, when traversing a `ShadowTree`, you cannot normally select descendants of `host` elements (which distributed nodes are), because they are in the "Shadow Realm" I mentioned earlier.

Comment: This is a phenomenal answer. Thank you so much for taking the time to write it!

Comment: @jon You're welcome! I'm glad you found it useful. There's also a [3rd tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/) by HTML5Rocks as well, if you are still looking for info.

Comment: The newline escaped by a backslash is not recommended because it's not ECMAScript

Comment: @TylerH In practice it'll be better to wrap the markup in a `<template>` tag.

Comment: @JuanMendes From what I've read just now, "The \ followed by a new line is not a character escape sequence, but a LineContinuation. The new line doesn’t become part of the string. This is simply a way to spread a string over multiple lines (for easier code editing, for example) [..]" [Source](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes). So it's not an escapement at all, apparently.

Comment: Just FYI: for further reading about Web Compontents You can visit a slideshow (" A future called Web Components") which was presented at Front Trends 2014 by Zeno Rocha (member at Google Developers Expert Program) - http://vimeo.com/97308701

Comment: @sboisse if you have a substantive reason for downvoting this answer, please share it.

Comment: Great answer! This is a well explained post, deserves thousands upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

Too bad! Unfortunately `::content` is **v0**, and was deprecated.

You should now use the **v1** `::slotted`.

Also, `<content>` was deprecated in favor of `<slot>`.

Please see: https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/

Also see: [Web Components - why <content> was replaced with <slot>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540025/web-components-why-content-was-replaced-with-slot/38558847?noredirect=1#comment64514932_38558847)