# What does ::content in CSS mean?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Wondering what does `::content` mean in a CSS selector. This is injected by the the [adguard-adblocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adguard-adblocker/bgnkhhnnamicmpeenaelnjfhikgbkllg/related?hl=en) plugin which I'm trying to disable or doing some work around to override it.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: These are the list of selectors: [W3C Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors). I couldn't find `::content`, which looks like Chrome Specific. Ha! There you are.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks Praveen. Looks like there is another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622605/what-is-the-content-pseudo-element-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Yes mate, I saw it... `:)`