# Styling `::slotted()` elements from the static styles property

Tags: css, polymer, lit-element

I'm trying to style the `:slotted` elements in a component from the static styles property as recommended in the docs.

```
static get styles() {
    return [
      css `
        ::slotted(*) {
          color: var(--white, #fff);
          font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        }
      `,
      // more styles...
     ]
}
```

But for some reason, is getting no effect.

Instead if define the same style in a style element into the `render()` function it works as expected

```html
    <style>
        ::slotted(*) {
          color: var(--white, #fff);
          font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        }
        // more styles...
    </style>
```

I'm not sure if this is expected (and why) or if this is a bug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622605/what-is-the-content-slotted-pseudo-element-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I know how `::slotted` works, I just need to know why it only works in litElement if I use it between the style tags and not in the styles property. Sorry, am I missing something from your response?

Comment: This is odd, your example should work. What browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a syntax problem in my example. I was using an style array.

This is working fine

```
static get styles(): CSSResultArray {
    return [ 
      css`
        :host {
          /* styles */
        }

        ::slotted(span) {
          /* styles */
        }
      `,
      css`
        :host([data-type="primary"]) button {
          /* styles */
        }
      `
      ];
  }
```

Comment: fyi, you shouldn't need multiple `css` expressions in the array, they can be combined. Array support is mainly for sharing styles between modules. You can also just return a single `css` expression instead of an array.

Comment: You are right, I used an array to better separate expressions by its responsibility. Not necessary but easier to read.