# @extend sass ampersand with ::slotted

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a style that's defined out of my reach, with an ampersand

```
.my-button {
    ...
    &:last-child {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to extend this from a selector with a `slotted` pseudo selector

```
.extended-button ::slotted(*) {
    @extend .my-button;
}
```

This results in css

```
.my-button:last-child,
.extended-button :last-child::slotted(*) {
    ...
}
```

But I want

```
.my-button:last-child,
.extended-button ::slotted(*:last-child) {
    ...
}
```

I searched for it, and found on the github of sass, that they support slotted elements. What exactly does that mean?

Anyone an idea what is happening here? How can I get the ampersand into the `slotted` pseudo selector?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to style a web component, otherwise `::slotted` or `::content` won't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622605/what-is-the-content-slotted-pseudo-element-and-how-does-it-work#27629265

Comment: @anderssonola That's exactly what I'm trying to do